# WCF web service: response is 200/ok, but response body is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a WCF web api service. My problem is that some methods return a 200/OK response, but the headers and the body are empty.

In setting up my web service, I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I chose ADO.NET DbContext Generator when I added a code generation item. In the Model.tt document, I changed HashSet and ICollection to List. I built my website.

It used to be that when I coded a method to return a List of an entity (like `List<Customer>` or `List<Employee>` in the Northwind database), it worked fine. Over time, I could not return a List of any of those, and could only grab one entity. Now, it's gotten to a point where I can return a `List<string>` or `List<int>`, but not a List or an instance of any entity. When I try to get a `List<AnyEntity>`, the response is 200/OK, but the response headers and body are empty.

I have tried using the debugger and Firefox's Web Console. Using FF's WC, I could only get an "undefined" status code. I am not sure where to go from here.

EDIT: In trying to grab all Areas from the database, I do this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "areas")]
public List<a1Areas> AllAreas()
{
    return context.a1Areas.ToList();
}
```

I would appreciate any more methods for debugging this. Thanks in advance.

Found the answer, thanks to Merlyn!

In my Global.asax file, I forgot to comment out two lines that took care of proxies and disposing of my context object. The code is below:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var context = new AssignmentEntities();
  context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
  HttpContext.Current.Items["_context"] = context;
}

void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var context = HttpContext.Current.Items["_context"] as AssignmentEntities;
  if (context != null)
  {
    context.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you returning entities directly to the client?  This might not work the way that you'd hope, due to entity proxies/lazy loading.  Can you supply some code for your service methods?  Also, Fiddler is a good tool for debugging requests.  Grabbing request and response data out of there and pasting it in the question might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the info! :)  How does your context get created/disposed?

Comment: Hello! Yes, I am returning the entities directly to the client. As for using Fiddler, the response was:  
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  
Connection: close  
Timestamp: 22:49:24.129  

ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about proxies! I took a look at my Global.asax file, where I created my context. I forgot to comment out a couple of lines: context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; and context.Dispose(). I will put the code to answer my own question, in case anyone has issues with this later. Thank you so much again!

Comment: No problem!  Feel free to post an actual answer to your own question and accept it.  That is accepted and encouraged here.

Comment: What do your entities look like?

Comment: I have this same problem with a rest enabled service. I am not using entities directly, so I am confused what that is causing a problem